# How to condense a json object based on a key in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4, anypoint-platform

I have a json structure as follows:

```
[
  {
    "apiId": 18211158,
    "policyName0": "cors"
    
  },
  {
    "apiId": 18211158,
    "policyName1": "client-id-enforcement"
  },
  {
    "apiId": 18211150,
    "policyName0": "client-id-enforcement"
  },
  {
    "apiId": 18211162,
    "policyName0": "client-id-enforcement"
  },
  {
    "apiId": 18211162,
    "policyName1": "cors"
  },
  {
    "apiId": 18211162,
    "policyName2": "oauth"
  }
]
```

I need to transform this into following using dataweave 2.0

```
[
  {
    "apiId": 18211158
    "policyName0": "cors",
    "policyName1": "client-id-enforcement",
  },
  {
    "apiId": 18211150
    "policyName0": "client-id-enforcement",
  },
  {
    "apiId": 18211162
    "policyName0": "client-id-enforcement",
    "policyName1": "cors",
    "policyName2": "oAuth",

  }
]
```

Note that each apiID can have multiple policies and the policyName json attribute is generated and cal have values ranging from 1 to 9.

How can I condense the json based on apiID as the key in dataweave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
payload groupBy $."apiId" pluck $ map {
    apiId: $."apiId"[0],
    policyName0: $.policyName0[0],
    policyName1: $.policyName1[0],
    policyName1: $.policyName2[0]
}
```

Output As below

```
[
  {
    "apiId": 18211158,
    "policyName0": "cors",
    "policyName1": "client-id-enforcement"
  },
  {
    "apiId": 18211150,
    "policyName0": "client-id-enforcement"
  },
  {
    "apiId": 18211162,
    "policyName0": "client-id-enforcement",
    "policyName1": "cors",
    "policyName1": "oauth"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is by using a groupBy with a pluck to reshape the groups into objects

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload 
    groupBy ((value, key) -> value.apiId)
    pluck ((value, key, index) -> {
            "apiId": key,
            (value map ((item, index) -> item - "apiId"))
        })
```

Comment: the issue with this answer is that if you have additional json elements in the json object then it adds them more than once.

Comment: You didn't mention that was a restriction in the question. You should have stated that as part of the problem. The answer does comply with the question as originally stated with the input shown.